# (JS) Используя циклы и условный оператор вывести все числа от 3 до 99, которые делятся нацело на 3. Числа разместить на странице по 5 штук в строке

Tags: javascript

**суть задачи:**

> Используя циклы и условный оператор вывести все числа от 3 до 99, которые делятся нацело на 3. 
> Числа разместить на странице по 5 штук в строке

Никак не могу найти решение ко второй части задания,
Не пойму суть операторов вывода в JS совершенно :)

Вот мой код:

```js
function myFunction13() {
  x = 0;
  for (i = 1; i <= 101; i++) {
    if (i % 3 == 0) {
      document.getElementById('out').innerHTML += i + " ";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<button type="button" name="button" id="demo" onclick="myFunction13()">
    Нажмите что бы увидеть числа
    </button>
<output id="out"> </output>
```

Comment: @progi_dev
Очень помогли ребят, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myFunction13() {
  x = 0;
  for (i = 1; i <= 99; i++) {
    if (i % 3 == 0) {
      document.getElementById('out').innerHTML += i + " ";
      x++;
    }
    if (x == 5) {
      document.getElementById('out').innerHTML += "\n";
      x = 0;
    }
  }
}
  // Если что, символ '\n' означает перевод строки, что нам и нужно.
```

```html
<button type="button" name="button" id="demo" onclick="myFunction13()">
        Нажмите что бы увидеть числа
        </button>
<pre id="out"> </pre>
```

Comment: Надеюсь, помог)

Comment: Только чтобы \n работал pre используйте

Comment: точно, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Можно несколькими путями, первое создавая див с 100% шириной.

```js
var i

function myFunction13() {
  var x = 0;
  for (i = 1; i <= 99; i++) {
    if (i % 3 == 0) {
      document.getElementById('out').innerHTML += i + " ";
      x++;
    }
    if (x == 5) {
      document.getElementById('out').innerHTML += '<div style="width: 100%"></div>';
      x = 0;
  }
}}
```

```html
<button type="button" name="button" id="demo" onclick="myFunction13()">
    Нажмите чтобы увидеть числа
    </button>
<output id="out"> </output>
```

Или через `<br>`'ы. **(Не рекомендуется)**

```js
var i

function myFunction13() {
  var x = 0;
  for (i = 1; i <= 99; i++) {
    if (i % 3 == 0) {
      document.getElementById('out').innerHTML += i + " ";
      x++;
    }
    if (x == 5) {
      document.getElementById('out').innerHTML += '<br />';
      x = 0;
  }
}}
```

```html
<button type="button" name="button" id="demo" onclick="myFunction13()">
    Нажмите чтобы увидеть числа
    </button>
<output id="out"> </output>
```